# PHP Credit Card payment gateway Integration

Tags: php, authorize.net

I need to develop an application which requires integration with credit card payment gateway and hence for testing i need a free developer account or any other possible account so that i can check whether the payment processing is correct or not.

So please specify me, if there exist some  payment gateway that allows the creation of a free account for testing.

If not is there any other solution,the application doesn't support paypal

Comment: This looks like a question to which half questions will be banned for promotion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Authorize.Net](http://www.authorize.net/) has a development environment you can integrate with.

Comment: but it doesn't provide a free account for test

Comment: No. But they do provide sample code in a myriad of programming languages, including PHP: http://developer.authorize.net/samplecode/.

Comment: yes you are right but you are aware of the fact that for using the code you will require login  and transaction key

Answer (score 1):

You can [apply for a free test account with Authorize.Net](http://developer.authorize.net/testaccount/). You can test all of their APIs as you would for a live integration with no cost to you.

Answer (score 0):

No two credit card APIs are the same, **don't integrate an API you don't intend to use.**

Also, every card processor will have his own quirks, just because you found one card processor that likes your API calls doesn't mean that the one you will intend to use will like your API calls.

Note that even the nomenclature in the specifications differs widely, authorizations are sometimes called reservations, preauthorizations, captures are sometime completions or charges, and purchases are sometimes sales, authorizations..... O.o

In short:

**If you implement one API, it has no merit on judging if another API will work**

---

Generally, credit card APIs fall into 2 basic categories:

1. **form APIs** - 3d secure is always implemented on the payment processor side and you don't need to do anything to ensure PCI compliance as credit card data is entered on the processor's site - in 90% of cases all you need to do is remote submit a form to the payment processor and catch a callback when transaction is processed
2. **direct APIs** - 3d secure must be implemented on your side in 90% of cases and you need to ensure a minimum of PCI DSS compliancy as credit card data is entered on your site (no storing of full PAN and CVV, SSL certificate, ...) - this one usually included 2 apis for processing authorizations (authorize/purchase and pares submit) and APIs for refund, capture of authorizations and void of authorizations

Note, you can usually use a form API to do authorizations and direct API for capture, refund and void.

See [PCI DSS Self Assessment Questionnaires for Merchants](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/merchants/self_assessment_form.php)

Other than that, going deeper would be going too broad, you will need to specify what kind of integration you are going for before I could elaborate.

To see examples of CC apis just google for "credit card processing api", I suggest you take a look at several of them to get a general feeling for things that are similar in many APIs and things that are different.